# How to Configure Customize Http,NHttp transports access_logs in wso2esb

Tags: http, tomcat7, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb-4.8.1.
I have read about  http_ access logs blog but I have small consult  like how we can customize the pattern.

Using below line in log4j.properties file I am getting Http,NHttp transports access logs.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.access=INFO
```

Using this property I am getting  Http,NHttp transport logs like below.

```
- 127.0.0.1  - [27/Jan/2015:14:59:54 +0330] "- - " 202 - "-" "-"
```

But I wish log the values in below format.

```
%{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss}t   %m %U %T %s %b %h %l %u

2015-01-26   14:36:03   POST /middleware/services/AuditService 0.022 200 428 127.0.0.1 - -
```

I have tried above format in tomcat 7 Its working fine,So I am expecting in wso2esb Because its using same flavor.

Where can I configure about Custom format for  Http ,NHttp transport access logs

I have searched for http_access_log file in wso2esb folder but i haven't get that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the http_access logs,  you can use [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/HTTP+Access+Logging) WSO2 doc for it. However,  i just want to mentioned that,  ESB is using pass through transport to communicate. Therefore if you need to see the HTTP request/response that is going through ESB,  you can enable the wire logs using `log4j.properties` file.  You just need to uncomment following and log pattern can be modified with `log4j.properties`

> log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
>   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG

Comment: Its not working because pattren hardcoded in org.apache.tranport.http.access file we have to modify in that file .for reference https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2598